# Is this possible to convert a fixed layout website into responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

One of my clients asked me to convert existing website into a responsive one.

The problem is: he doesn't want to change its desktop view. That website was completely developed with fixed layout in codeigniter.

Is it possible to make it into a responsive one without many changes to exiting css?

[check out this url](http://www.mahindraearthmaster.com/)

Comment: Every design could be converted to responsive using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: i need little help that how can.
there are fix width in px of every element.
have i to change entire css or media query only ?
should i change structure also?

Comment: Each media query get an amount of screen size (like min-width: 400px - max-width: 480px;) so once user browser has this size the rules that you put inside this query will run.

Comment: Please try to goole 'introduction to media queries'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can convert fixed design in responsive via help of 2 method

1. use media queries as suggested by emmanuel.
2. use % instead of px it will help your website responsive over many platform and then use media query if you are required to shift or position the content according to your design necessity

Comment: is this possible to convert all 17 pages into responsive by one developer in 6 working days ?

just i am asking your opinion  ?

Comment: it can be done in time of max 2 days if you know what you are doing

Comment: 6 working days? Sounds too tough. ;)

Comment: it is easy just make fixed layout size as base and calculate % for its content